# Display last 10 git tags with "Pv1" prefix

Tags: git, shell

I want to display last to tags with prefix "Pv1".

i'm only bale to list in order but was not able to get them with a prefix as i want to eliminate staging tags. with following command.

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" --sort=-taggerdate --count=10 refs
```

and got following results.

```
refs/tags/Pv1.155.0
refs/tags/QAv1.154.1
refs/tags/Pv1.154.0
refs/tags/QAv1.153.1
refs/tags/Pv1.153.0
refs/tags/Pv1.152.0
refs/tags/QAv1.151.1
refs/tags/Pv1.151.0
refs/tags/QAv1.150.1
refs/tags/Pv1.150.0_p1
```

But I only want to "Pv1" tags.  I want them for for shell script. I don't want it to grep and then filter. I tried `--contains=` bus was not able to successfully execute the command.

Comment: What's wrong with grep?

Comment: The problem is what if the first 8 results are with prefix QAv1, then I end up with only two usable values, i can get last 15 results but that is not also trial and error. So wanted to get it with git options first and if all fails then i'll get 20 results and hope they have 5 results with desired prefix.

Comment: Unless your repository is absolutely enormous, it shouldn't be a problem to just fetch all the tags, then filter with `grep` and `head`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [non-dash-prefixed arguments to `git for-each-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html) are [*glob patterns:*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))

> <pattern>...
>
>   If one or more patterns are given, only refs are shown that match against at least one pattern, either using fnmatch(3) or literally, in the latter case matching completely or from the beginning up to a slash.

Hence you just need a glob pattern that matches `refs/tags/Pv1*`, which is of course `refs/tags/Pv1*`.

(Note that if you don't include any glob-pattern characters in a `for-each-ref` pattern, Git adds `/*` to the end for you.  In other words, `git for-each-ref refs/heads` is equivalent to `git for-each-ref refs/heads/*`.  Git is smart enough to not add an extra slash , so you can write `git for-each-ref refs/heads/` if you like.)

Comment: Thank  
git for-each-ref 'refs/tags/Pv1*' --count=5 --format="%(refname)" --sort=-taggerdate
did the trick.